# ANDROID -- How to display text on an image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

Ok...so here's the scenario.. Starting from scratch, I want to display THREE stars (i have an image that I want to use), centered. I want to post a different word in each star. Of course, I do not want it hard-coded, but once I can get the layout right, the rest will be easy. Can anyone help please? I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean hardcoded ? you want to do it on from the xml file ? if so I would try playing with Relative layout to overlap a image view with and text view and create your star element. otherwise you could create a custom view that takes a text and displays it above the star automatically anc you can call that element form your code

Answer (score 3):

If you're wanting to just overlay text on top of an image, just wrap the ImageView in a FrameLayout, and then just define a TextView after the ImageView. It will be layered on top. For what you're suggesting in your initial question, Reuben and Yahel's answers will be the better way.

Example:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Text on Top!"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "background" property that *every* View has, including TextView, to put the star(s) in. Job done.

Comment: So... if I want to show text inside of a custom image, I should use TextView? Or something like ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the android:background attribute of your TextViews.