# how to write text on the image view?

Tags: android, android-layout, text, fonts, android-emulator

i need to implement a text on the image view where user can type his text on the image view . how can we implement text according to the user  and add fonts according to the user?

here is my **full image activity class**

```
     public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullimage);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }

}
```

**fullimage.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you will have to use a relative layout which will place a edittext above imageview, and make the edittext as tranparent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019517/android-how-to-display-text-on-an-image. check this

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Your Text"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

**Note**: It would Work only in `RELATIVE LAYOUT`

or Try the below code

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_drawable);
t.setText("your text");
```

FOR **`EDITEXT`**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"  >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How can a user type a text on TextView in android?

Comment: when i am using relative layout the image is not all fit the screen and the text should be set according to the user?

Comment: whole screen should have that imageview and wherever the user touches the edittext should appear or user can type the text.. Is this what you are trying to do???

Comment: that is the correct what you typed above .i am searching for it?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263384/android-how-to-get-text-position-from-touch-event

Answer (score 0):

According to your need, add ImageView and EditText in a RelativeLayout:-

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  //or any other alignment you want
    android:text="ABCD"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: when i am using relative layout the image not all fitting in to the full screen the text should be typed and set on the image view according to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Add relative layout and then add imageview and on top of it add textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_favorites" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an Frame layout like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Text" Visibility="Gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In Code, when the user touches a particular position on the imageview, show the textview there by setting the margin for textview

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" // set gravity as per your requirement to show
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: whole screen should have that imageview and wherever the user touches can type the text???

Answer (score 0):

This work fine.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fb_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: on the top of the image view the user should type his own text?

Comment: The problem is that not displaying the text.The user should display his own text by using custom text interfence

Comment: did you try 
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById;
tv.setText(Variable);

Comment: can you provide me a little bit of your code where you declare?

Comment: i had defined in the full image activity class

Comment: from where you get values to define text on ImageView?