# How to write my name on a image

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

**I want to change the my name and designation which in on ImageView** but not making a layout. I want to write it on image at runtime. I just want to select the image and put my name and after writing on image I want to upload on server.I am unable to  write on image without making layout .

[image]

Comment: try with use frame layout you can write name on image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANDROID -- How to display text on an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019517/android-how-to-display-text-on-an-image)

Comment: it means you want to generate image with your name address etc runtime
not a layout. is it ok?

Comment: Please read the que   sir ...i dont want tomake layout i had already mention .

Comment: You could generate your final image directly with PHP on the server using some parameters for your script to be processed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try
 Use `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout 
   .....
   .....>

     <ImageView 
           ..
           ../>

<Other layout like TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then [Take screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868604/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-of-an-android-layout)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class extends Imageview,

and override onDraw method,

in that

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
        canvas.drawPaint(paint); 

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        paint.setTextSize(20); 
        canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint);
}
```

put this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one **it return you bitmap with your text** i just put code it may help you.

```
private BitmapDrawable writeTextOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text) {

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId)
                .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Helvetica", Typeface.BOLD);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTypeface(tf);
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(mContext, 11));

        Rect textRect = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);

        //If the text is bigger than the canvas , reduce the font size
        if(textRect.width() >= (canvas.getWidth() - 4))     //the padding on either sides is considered as 4, so as to appropriately fit in the text
            paint.setTextSize(convertToPixels(mContext, 7));        //Scaling needs to be used for different dpi's

        //Calculate the positions
        int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - 2;     //-2 is for regulating the x position offset

        //"- ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)" is the distance from the baseline to the center.
        int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)) ;  

        canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, paint);

        return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
    }



    public static int convertToPixels(Context context, int nDP)
    {
        final float conversionScale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        return (int) ((nDP * conversionScale) + 0.5f) ;

    }
```

Comment: public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    writeTextOnDrawable(R.drawable.testcard, "ABCD");
    
   } it is not working when i am calling it on click of a button nothing happens

Comment: is there any error??  do u put setonclicklistner in button??

Comment: There is not any error, nothing reflecting on Image View.  Already put setonClickListener on button.

Comment: its work for me complete chek your image not white .. iv.setImageBitmap(writeTextOnDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "yoyoyoyo").getBitmap());

Comment: do you get your solution or not?

Comment: Nope, I think Samoth suggestion is correct for me..."You could generate your final image directly with PHP on the server using some parameters for your script to be processed dynamically"

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create a layout then you can use a TextView and set the selected image to its background and write the text by setting its gravity else you can override the onDraw method of ImageView.

Comment: To me it looks like an attempt to answer the question.